# Vaadin 14: using two types of drag&drop within the same Grid

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, vaadin, vaadin-grid, vaadin14

Does any of you deep experience regarding D&D (drag&drop) functionality in Vaadin 14? I have already implemented D&D between Layout and Component, and also could implemented the D&D within Grid. What I did not find that how I could solve that kind of solution when you have a TreeGrid and you could handle internal (from Grid) and external drop (a Component) as well. Is there any solution for this? It looks that two options decline each other. Thx.

Comment: To clarify: are you trying to drop the component to a details row, or to a regular Grid cell?

Comment: It should be possible to drag Components and drop them on a (Tree)Grid row, and vice versa, as long as the DropEffect is the same. Of course, you'll need to implement the action in a drop listener.